# Probability: What is the best solution for this problem about Discrete distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Here is the problem:

***The drainage system of a city has been designed for a rainfall intensity that will  be exceeded on an average once in 50 years.
What is the probability that the city will be flooded at most 2 out of 10 years?***

May you tell me what do you think about my solution?

In my perspective, we can use the Binomial or the Poisson Distribution.

However, I think that the precise one, is the Poisson because of this explanation of my book, the ninth edition of Probability and Statistical Inference written by Robert Hogg, Elliot Tanis and Dale Zimmerman.

Please read it:

[image: Poisson Distribution]

In despite of that, the same book talks also about the Binomial Distribution.

Please read it:

[image]

Which solution would be the best solution?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: there is no "best answer" from a straight math point of view.  This is a modeling question.  We are not told anything about the distribution other than its mean.  If, for example, the heavy rain falls exactly once every $50$ years then the answer to your question is $0$.  That is an entirely consistent approach, though probably not realistic.  I do expect that Poisson resembles reality a bit better, but I should think the answer you get from a binomial model would be very similar.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it a lot. May you expand more your comment "I do expect that Poisson resembles reality a bit better"? Why do you consider that Poisson would be a bit better than Binomial?

Comment: The simplifying assumption should, I think, be that the probability of heavy rain is equal in all intervals of equal duration.  That is obviously violated by my caricature model, for example.  It is also violated in nature but for present purposes we need some simplifying assumptions.  That assumption is best modeled analytically by Poisson.  But, really, it makes little difference.  Barring blunder I get $0.999136094$ for the binomial and $0.999998687$ for Poisson.  Very close.

Comment: Worth noting that Poisson is more tractable analytically; an advantage that should not be discounted.  Not a big deal in this case since neither approach is especially complex.

Comment: Should also say:  in my caricature model (first comment) I was looking at the probability of getting more than $1$ year of heavy rain in a ten year span.  That is $0$, which makes the answer to your question $1$ with this (silly) model.

Comment: @lulu Should lambda be equal to 0.2 and not 1/50? Because Lambda is the mean, and the mean for 10 years would be (1/50)*10= 0.2. I am right or wrong? I think that the current calcution is showing the probability in 50 years, but the problem asks for 10 years.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I was, incorrectly, just running it for a single year.

Comment: Per comments, I have revised my Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen two promising possible models. I botched my first try at
a good explanation, but was kindly nudged onto the right track in Comments by @lulu.

**Poisson.** If the rate of floods is $1$ per 50 years, then it is $\lambda_{10} = 1/5 = 0.2$ per ten years. Thus, let $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_{10} = 1/5),$ which has $E(X) = 1/5.$ Then using the formula for the Poisson PDF (or PMF) one gets
$P(X \le 2) =  0.9989.$ or essentially a 'sure thing'. The computation in R
statistical software is shown below:

```
ppois(2, .2)
## 0.9988515
```

**Binomial.** Suppose we try modeling with a binomial random variable $Y.$
Because a 10-year time span is envisioned, let $n = 10.$ We need 
$E(Y) = np = 10p = 1/5,$ so $p = 1/50 = 0.02.$ Then $P(Y \le 2) = 0.9991 \approx 1,$
which is nearly the same result as for the Poisson model.

```
pbinom(2, 10,.02)
## 0.9991361
```

I used R statistical software to do the computations, but you should probably use the formulas for Poisson and binomial probabilities.

Here is a plot with the Poisson model represented as bars and the binomial model
represented as red circles. For both models, almost all of the probability rests on 0 or 1 serious floods. (I had to make a tall plot for the probability of *two* storms
in 10 years to show on the graph.)

[image]

*Note:* Binomial distributions can often be approximated by Poisson distributions with the same mean. In the case where $\mu = np$ remains
constant, while $n \rightarrow \infty$ (and $p$ shrinks appropriately)
it can be shown that the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(n,p)$ converges to
that of $\mathsf{Pois}(\mu).$ [An essential element of the proof
is that $(1 - a/n)^n \rightarrow e^{-a}.]$

Comment: Why do you use $\frac 1{2500}$ for the binomial success probability?  We expect one incident in $50$ trials so surely $p=\frac 1{50}$, no?

Comment: I see you have switched it from $\frac 1{2500}$ to $\frac 1{500}$ but I still think it ought to be $\frac 1{50}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Please give me your thoughts and your opinion. Which one do you think is the best solution? Binomial or Poisson? In this case, the answers are similar, but for other cases could be different, right? I also different question. Should lambda be equal to 0.2 and not 1/50? Because Lambda is the mean, and the mean for 10 years would be (1/50)*10= 0.2. I am right or wrong? I think that the current calcution is showing the probability in 50 years, but the problem asks for 10 years.

Comment: Not following.  If you have a success rate of $p=\frac 1{500}$ in a single year, then the expected number of successes in $50$ years is $\frac 1{10}$.

Comment: @lulu. You are usually right about these things, including this time. I have thought it through over the last few hours and made appropriate changes. Also deleted one of my previous comments, part of which was wrong, for fear it added to the confusion. Thanks for your helpful objections.

Comment: I tried to edit this myself but it required more characters to change which I did not see fit but: in your last line you recall a well known fact about exponential function but it seems you've forgotten an exponent; you've written "$(1-a/n) \to e^{-a}$".

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for the update! Very nice! Can you please answer which one you think is the most precise for this problem? Of course the result is basically the same, but one must be the right one, and the other the approximation. What is your opinion about it?

Comment: My guess is the text/instructor intended this to be a Poisson problem. Poisson dist'n is often used to model 'rare events'. (But you should try to understand how the binomial model works and about the Pois approx to binomial.)

Comment: @BruceET Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Did you see @LoveTooNap29 comment?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29: Fixed typo, thanks. $(1-2/1000)^{1000} = 0.1350645.$ and $e^{-2}=0.1353353
.$